# Smooth changing background-color of body while scrolling in Fullpage.js

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, fullpage.js

I use fullpage.js and I want to change background-color smoothly of body while scrolling. I saw this effect [here](https://moneytree.jp/). This site also use Fullpage.js and I want to add this effect to my site.
I create a [jsFiddle with fullpage example here](https://jsfiddle.net/132cdjs3/). 
Site with smooth color uses `mt-data-slide-bg-color="#f4efec"` and some javascript code to fullpage function. This function locates here (link in comments). So but if I add this code to my example it doesn't work.

Please help me.

Comment: [Smooth function of site here](https://moneytree.jp/wp-content/themes/mt-wordpress-theme/assets/js/moneytree-slides.js?ver=4.2.8)

Comment: Please post what you've done in your code that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can animate colours using [jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/animate/).

Then, change the `body` color and leave sections and slides without any background color or image.