# Gradient smooth scroll on fullpage.js

Tags: gradient, fullpage.js

http://www.symodd.com/ i really like the way the gradient changes on this website. i know that its using Fullpage.js for the scrolling but i cant figure out the gradient 
so far i have tried changing the sectioncolor using JqueryUI but i cant figure out how to do the gradient

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#f4efec to ', '#f4e0e9', '#f4d9d0', '#f4e3c9', '#b5dce1', '#d7e0b1'],
    navigation: true ,
    menu: '#fp-nav'
});
```

});

Comment: It's mainly the smooth transition of the gradient I'm trying to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378872/smooth-changing-background-color-of-body-while-scrolling-in-fullpage-js/37379455#37379455

Comment: Sorry i pasted the wrong link :D